# Drawing precision, straight lines on animated surface

Tags: texturing, uv

so the problem is that I have a with bones animated plane that moves and bends and so on. Now I need a completely straight, clear and thin line at the exact middle of the surface, what also moves along with the plane. This line also has to be hideable through parts of the animation.

I tried to use lines but I couldn't find out how to make them following the movements of the surface, and I also tried to fix this problem with UV-Mapping, but I can't find out how to make precision lines and how I could hide them in parts of my animation.

I'm very thankful for any help!

Comment: How about rendering it with [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html)?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

This will work dynamically with a mesh or a curve. If you need to animate the curve handles, use the hook modifier to parent them to armature bones.